# Azure Membership UI

Tags: azure, membership-provider

Using AspProviders (TableStorageMembershipProvider etc) from Microsoft [WCF Azure Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wcfazure/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4927).
It is WCF Service Web Role, and in Azure Storage Explorer I can see Membership, Roles and Session tables appearing nicely when I try to connect.
But is there any exisiting code to manage Membership and Roles?
Some ASPX pages I guess, something like [this](http://peterkellner.net/2006/01/09/microsoft-aspnet-20-memberrole-management-with-iis/) for plain old ASP.NET, but more modern and Azure-tested hopefully?

Thanks,
Andres

Comment: Hi Andres, thanks for posting this. Can you contact me on twitter on @ashleyrudland, I want to ask you some more questions please!

Comment: One can't contact on twitter non-followers, sorry. Please provide other contact if still interested

Answer (score 2):

To my surprise, [Peter Kellner's solution](http://peterkellner.net/2006/01/09/microsoft-aspnet-20-memberrole-management-with-iis/) I mentioned works just fine. Here are the steps to follow: Add AspProviders (from [WCF Azure Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wcfazure/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4927)) to your solution. Create Azure ASP.NET Web Role (let's call it MembershipAdmin), reference AspProviders from it. Add Membership.aspx and other aspx/cs files from [Peter Kellner's solution](http://peterkellner.net/2006/01/09/microsoft-aspnet-20-memberrole-management-with-iis/), mark Membership.aspx as "Set As Start Page". In MembershipAdmin's Web.config, find and replace sections "membership" and "roleManager", and add section "appSettings" (the latter goes directly under root configuration). Examples of these sections are below, just change "YourTargetService" to what your real service name is. Actually it's going to mirror Web.config of your real service, regarding these sections (well, you need a few more tricks there, too - as a matter of completeness I'd like to mention I got help from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2009/11/19/using-the-sample-windows-azure-asp-net-providers.aspx) and [here](http://blog.shutupandcode.net/?p=948)). Then just run, and appearing Membership.aspx is quite self explaining. Of course securing that page will be obviously your next worry, but at least now roles/users can be managed, and they appear nicely into Azure Table Storage.

```
<membership defaultProvider="TableStorageMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="20">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="TableStorageMembershipProvider" type="Microsoft.Samples.ServiceHosting.AspProviders.TableStorageMembershipProvider" description="Membership provider using table storage" applicationName="YourTargetService" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" minRequiredPasswordLength="1" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
    </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="TableStorageRoleProvider" cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieName=".ASPXROLES" cookieTimeout="30" cookiePath="/" cookieRequireSSL="false" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" cookieProtection="All">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="TableStorageRoleProvider" type="Microsoft.Samples.ServiceHosting.AspProviders.TableStorageRoleProvider" description="Role provider using table storage" applicationName="YourTargetService" />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
<appSettings>
    <add key="TableStorageEndpoint" value="http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1" />
    <add key="BlobStorageEndpoint" value="http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1" />
    <add key="AccountName" value="devstoreaccount1" />
    <add key="AccountSharedKey" value="Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==" />
    <add key="DefaultMembershipTableName" value="Membership" />
    <add key="DefaultRoleTableName" value="Roles" />
    <add key="DefaultSessionTableName" value="Sessions" />
    <add key="DefaultProviderApplicationName" value="YourTargetService" />
    <add key="DefaultProfileContainerName" />
    <add key="DefaultSessionContainerName" />
</appSettings>
```